# Insert digital signature on PDF Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext, digital-signature, pdfbox

I am getting the pdf link from serve. I want to get the users digital signature like shown below,

[image]

This signature I can capture and save the bitmap.

Now I want to insert this signature to the pdf which is fetched from the server as shown below.

[image]

Once user clicks on done, I shold generate updated pdf file with the signature captured from the user.

I did google search on this and found that with PDFBox it can be achieved.
Can anyone let me know how to achieve this with Pdf box or is there any other alternative solution.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to add an image to an existing PDF. Did you try any code? See also the `AddImageToPDF.java` example from the desktop source code.

Comment: Yes. How can I do that

Comment: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddImageToPDF.java?view=markup

Comment: this will give the final result as image. But I want to get the updated pdf file as result with the image added at the signature place

Comment: Ooops I see you mean an digital signature, i.e. not just an image. In that case, try this: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java?view=markup or https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature2.java?view=markup however I suspect that there are some differences in the Android version. But if you really just meant an image and no verification, then change the AddImage code so that the position is changed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I want to add a digital signature with verification. Do you have any working sample on GitHub which I can go through?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202375/discussion-between-hasan-shaikh-and-tilman-hausherr).

Comment: I only do PDFBox for desktop, so I can't help with Android, sorry. But I can help with result files. I suggest you try to come up with actual code for Android (see also past issues there), and then create a new question, and delete this one.